# Find smallest element in a sorted rotated array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My function to find the lowest element in alphabetical order in a sorted rotated array seems to work when the element is in the middle of the array and when the element is at the beginning of the array.  What I cannot figure out is how to get the code to work when the element is at the end of the array. The smallest element in "Anna". Here is my code

```
function sorted_array(arr){
        var first = 0;
        var middle = arr.length/2;
        var last = arr.length-1;

    while(true){
        if(arr[middle-1] > arr[middle] && arr[middle+1] > arr[middle] || middle === first
            || middle == last){
            return arr[middle];
        }
        if(arr[middle] > arr[last] ){
            first = middle;
            middle = Math.floor((middle + last)/2);
        } else{
            last = middle;
            middle = Math.floor((first + middle)/2);
        }
    }
}


var arr = [  "Celeste",
 "Elon", "Giggli", "Jay", "Mavis", "Phoebe",  "Thunder", "Anna"];
console.log(sorted_array(arr));
```

Comment: smallest in legth ?

Comment: smallest in order

Comment: @Mahi asked, according to what parameter are the elements ordered and then, yes, the smallest of them, i.e. *the first*.

Comment: @Aaron do you need alphabetic order ?

Comment: Seems like if the actual problem is sorting an array of strings and taking the first element in that list, `arr.sort().shift();` is the simplest solution

Comment: @RobM. it is not the same: while sorting an array is an O(N*logN) operation, searching for the minimum in a sorted array takes only O(logN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move the `middle` pointer, you need to round it up, e.g. `(middle + left + 1)/2` in the part where you search the later part of the array. Otherwise you will never reach the last item.

In your case you get `middle = 6, last = 7`, `(6+7)/2 = 6,5 ==> 6`.

Also in your stopping condition, you should check if `middle === last || middle === first` before the value check to prevent invalid index errors.